# Can't type capital letters in virtual machine over TeamViewer

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, remote-desktop

I have a computer that I access remotely using TeamViewer. The remote computer is running Linux Mint 17.2, and my local computer is running Windows 10. On this remote computer, I have several VMs I need to access.

When I start up one of those VMs, I am unable to type upper case letters. However, I am able to paste using the `shift+insert` key combination. Also, if I use the terminal to set Caps Lock on the remote host, then I can send capital letters to the VM.

Why might this be? I'm using VirtualBox to run my virtual machines. It seems that it's able to get the shift key as well as combinations, it just doesn't type upper case letters when I connect through TeamViewer!

Comment: Note, if I install teamviewer in one of those virtual machines and connect directly, then I can type upper case letters. This problem is new, so I'm not sure why it's not working from Keyboard -> TeamViewer (linux) -> VM (windows). I've tried with several different clients / keyboards with the same results.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No, I haven't yet